# locale not getting set correctly over ssh connection

Tags: debian, localization

I have a debian server with several locales installed, de_DE, en_GB and en_US. I want to be able to login over ssh and get the locale set accordingly (to en_US in my case, different for someone else)
I ran dpkg-reconfigure locales, and selected None as the default locale as mentioned here: http://wiki.debian.org/Locale.
Now, when I login over ssh I still get the de_DE locale.

```
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LANGUAGE=de_DE.utf8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8
```

I checked with ssh -v, the ssh client is indeed sending the LANG variable

```
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

How is the locale still getting set to DE and how can I disable that behavior?

**Edit:** It works now. Someone forcibly set the locale in /etc/profile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Someone hard coded the `LC_ALL` and `LANG` variables in `/etc/profile`, so everything else was just ignored. After removing these, the locale now gets set according to the environment transmitted by ssh.

Comment: This happened to me too - after a fresh installation of Ubuntu. It turned out my hosting provider manipulated certain files without documenting it. The answer worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Is specifying the user-preferred locale configurations in ~/.profile appropriate for your needs?

Also, to save you the annoyance, stop forwarding locale from your client (/etc/ssh/ssh_config, comment out SendEnv LANG...) and stop accepting on the server (/etc/ssh/sshd_config)..

Or, if you prefer, you can set a ~/.ssh/environment file with the options you want.  You'll have to enable PermitUserEnvironment on the server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

Comment: I think the forwarding of the locale is not the problem, I actually want that to work. The server not accepting or rather not setting the locale accordingly is the problem. Setting it explicitly in .profile would work. But I was wondering where the system still gets the German locale from.

Answer (score 2):

Also please check this file:

`/etc/default/locale`

*if you make it empty then it may help too.*

next to already mentioned:

```
/etc/profile
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

each of those files may include some of

```
LANG
LANGUAGE
LC_*
```

Comment: I found this was my problem after enabling `LogLevel DEBUG3` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. After doing `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` I could clearly see an entry here for: `sshd[3315840]: debug3: Copy environment: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`

This is why my language was never set. After commenting out the `/etc/default/locale` it worked! 

**However**, I do not feel this is an appropriate fix so I will just run `export LANG=en_US` when connecting until I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when logging in with ssh none of the usual default locale or environment variable settings seemed to work. It was because I had disabled PAM session control in sshd configuration.

Make sure you have set

```
UsePAM yes
```

in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, at least this worked for me.